# No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Int32[]'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I execute a SQL Server stored procedure from Entity Framework Core (v2.0) in my ASP.NET Core project, I get this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: no mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Int32[]'

The SQL Server stored procedure code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp-UpdateProductOrderAndStock]
    @customerOrderID INT,
    @qty INT
AS
    DECLARE @customerProductID INT
    SET @customerProductID = (SELECT CustomerProductID 
                              FROM dbo.CustomerOrder 
                              WHERE ID = @customerOrderID)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    UPDATE dbo.CustomerOrder
    SET CompletedQty = CompletedQty + @qty
    WHERE ID = @customerOrderID;

    UPDATE dbo.CProductStation
    SET Qty = Qty - @qty
    WHERE CustomerProductID = @customerProductID AND StationNo = 0;
```

ASP.NET Core data model as below:

```
public class CustomerProductDelivery
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerOrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryNo { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryQty { get; set; }
    public CustomerOrder CustomerOrder { get; set; }
}
```

ASP.net core Controller code to execute the stored procedure:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp-UpdateProductOrderAndStock @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID,customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty });
```

Comment: The stored procedure is called `[dbo].[Update_ProductOrderAndStock]` - but you're calling a procedure called `sp-UpdateProductOrderAndStock` from EF Core ..... those names **must match** !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TLDR**

Use string interpolation

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Update_ProductOrderAndStock {customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID}, {customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty}");
```

**Detailed answer:**

You are falling into a typical `params object[]` trap.

First, let see what's the type of the expression

```
var parameters = new[] { customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID,customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty }
```

Since both elements are of type `int`, the inferred type is `int[]`.

Now, there are 2 `ExecuteSqlCommand` method overloads which allow you to pass parameters separately - one receiving `params object[]` and second receiving `IEnumerable<object>`.

Although `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, covariance does not work for value types, so `IEnumerable<int>` cannot be treated as `IEnumerable<object>`, hence the second overload does not match.

So the only valid overload is the one receiving `params object[]`. But since `int[]` cannot be cast to `object[]`, the compiler treats it as *single* `object`, thus emitting something like `new object[] { parameters }`.

The net effect is that the EF method receives single parameter with `int[]` type value and generates the exception in question.

With that being said, it could be fixed in many ways.

One is to remove `new [] { }` from the call, which is the whole idea of `params object[]` construct:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "Update_ProductOrderAndStock @p0, @p1", customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID, customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty);
```

Another is to replace the `new []` with the explicit `new object[]`.

Yet another one is to utilize the EF Core introduced [String interpolation in FromSql and ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#string-interpolation-in-fromsql-and-executesqlcommand):

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    $"Update_ProductOrderAndStock {customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID}, {customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty}");
```

Answer (score 7):

Please update the code

from

```
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                   "sp_UpdateProductOrderAndStock @p0, @p1", parameters: 
                     new[] 
                     { 
                        customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID,customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty
                      });
```

to

```
List<SqlParameter> pc = new List<SqlParameter>
{
   new SqlParameter("@customerOrderID", customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderI),
   new SqlParameter("@qty", customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty)
}

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_UpdateProductOrderAndStock @customerOrderID, @qty", pc.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you Md.Abdul Alim, Database don't have ExecuteSqlQuery method, i changed to ExecuteSqlCommand method, got information as below:SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'UpdateProductOrderAndStock'.

Comment: sql query not accept '-' but '_'. You should change your procedure name sp-UpdateProductOrderAndStock to sp_UpdateProductOrderAndStock. Then it will work

Comment: change _context.Database.ExecuteSqlQuery to _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand, then test ok

Answer (score 0):

Another Answer

```
var p0 = new SqlParameter("@customerOrderID", customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID);
        var p1 = new SqlParameter("@qty", customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty);
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_UpdateProductOrderAndStock @customerOrderID, @qty", p0, p1);

        //or  var p0 = new SqlParameter("@p0", customerProductDelivery.CustomerOrderID);
        //or  var p1 = new SqlParameter("@p1", customerProductDelivery.DeliveryQty);
        // or _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_UpdateProductOrderAndStock @p0, @p1", p0, p1);
```